# Probability with real numbers

Tags: probability

There are two sets of real numbers: $S_1=[0,N_1]$, $S_2=[0,N_2]$, where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are positive integers. From $S_1$ a value $x_1$ and from $S_2$ a value $x_2$ is chosen.

What will be the probability that $x_1=x_2$?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{P}(\text{we pick the value $x_1$ from $S_1$}) = 0$.

Comment: @Ritz can u please explain

Comment: @chef4194, you have infinitely many real numbers between $[0, N_1]$. Unless $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers, the problem won't be that interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loss of generality, suppose $N_2 \ge N_1$, and we divide the intersect $[0,N_1]$ to M small blocks and similarly $[0,N_2]$ to $\frac{N_2}{N_1}M$ blocks.

We can find the probability that the point is in the same block is 
$\Sigma_{i=1}^{M}\frac{1}{M}{\frac{N_1}{N_2M}} = \frac{N_1}{N_2M} $

Let M increase to infinity, it's $lim_{M->\infty}\frac{N_1}{N_2M} = 0 $

Comment: What will be the probability that x2-x1<=y, where y is an integer number?

Comment: @chef4194 it's more complicate, you should discuss the relationship between $N_1 + y$ and $N_2$. You can work out by modifying the probability function, which now should be also related to i.

Comment: Will you please provide some more explanation.